# Decal Machine 2.51 Libraries not showing up

Tags: add-on

I installed the Decal Machine addon. No decals are showing up in the pie menu. Under preferences the Update The All! button stays inactive. I click the install PIL button, that seems to work.

I have gone through the documentation online, nothing references this problem.

Comment: if you paid over 50$ for an add-on...you should ask the creator for help.

Comment: I have sent message already but no response